# SonarQube Post Custom Results

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-api

We have a process to produce any violations related to secrets in code. These violations can be in any type of code files, for example XML, jsom, configs or c#, Java code files. Our scanner runs as part of VSTS build pipeline and produces a json file with list of issues. We would like to post these issues to sonarqube without writing any rules again.

Is there a sample or easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look here: [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460552/posting-custom-scan-results) SO question.